# Query multiple Google Analytics ID's using Python

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

The Google Analytics API has a parameter called [ids](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#ids) the documentation states

> The unique ID used to retrieve the Analytics data.

Is there a way to query Google Analytics to pull data from multiple ID views? If not, how would I iterate through multiple View IDs?

Comment: No you can't. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26460861/742269

Answer (score 0):

The [Google analytics API v3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#ids) only returns results for one view at a time.   However the batch mode from this api does support sending requests with different ids.

The new [Google Analytics reporting api V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet) is batch based. This means that you can send more then one report request at a time.  However you can't send reports with different view ids